# How can I get status of build in declarative pipeline below

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
script{
    build job : 'somejob', 
    parameters: [
        extendedChoice(name: 'some_choice', value: "${env.some_choice}")
    ], 
    propagate: false  
} 
echo  "${currentBuild.Currentresult}
```

How can I get status of build job in above declarative pipeline
`${currentBuild.Currentresult}`  always return success

Answer (score 0):

just access it as currentBuild. For example, in my code, I passing buildStatus to a library like below:

```
stage('notify') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "end!!"
                    slackHelper.finalBuildStatusMessage(currentBuild)
                    slackSend(channel: '#ci-cd', attachments: slackHelper.getFinalSlackMessage())
                }
            }
        }
```